# Downloading images only for visible UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

In `UITableViewController` I have **custom cells** with thumbnail image which is cached by me using [`TMCache`](https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache/). So the basic workflow of loading cells is:

1. Fill cell lables with data from model
2. Check if I have a thumbnail image cached
3. If yes, than get it from cache...
4. If not, download it from web...

And me concerns are that when I don't have anything in cache I'd start downloading a lot of images (even if I have set maximum number of concurrent tasks) so when the user scrolls for example a 100 rows my `tasks` array in `AFHTTPSessionManager` will be dealing with all of then even if user is not interested in many of them.

So I came with this solution:
When usere scrolls down and downloading begins, but in a moment this cell gets off the screen, I want to cancel `NSURLSessionDataTask`for this cell. But... I don't know how to check which cell should cancel its task and the more important issue, what if task is completed in 90% and I cancel it (waste of data transfer)? I've noticed that in Facebook app they're not cancelling those tasks because when you scroll up they are loaded.

**I wonder if this is a good approach or maybe I'm trying to overcomplicate everything?**

Comment: Possible solution: Why not just cap the number of outstanding requests at something like 10. If the user is scrolling through 10 items faster than it takes to load a single item then they are probably not interested.

Comment: What if they scrolled fast to line #100? You will stuck loading images from cell 1-10 and user will be looking at empty cell #100.

Comment: @sha They would not be stuck waiting for cells 1-10 to load. As soon as cell 11 becomes visible it would cancel the loading for cell 1 (if it was still outstanding). If you scrolled fast to line 100 it would begin loading it immediately, you just might not have finished loading any of the cells you scrolled past.

Comment: @CrimsonChris and how you'd limit `AFHTTPSessionManager` to fit your solution? I have no idea if it's even possible!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Specifically, you can use the following methods to track cells' appearance and disappearance:

```
– tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

- tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

Answer (score 1):

Why waste bandwidth? Do this:

in `UITableViewControllerDataSource::cellForRowAtIndexPath:` start a timer to go off in, say 200 ms or something, which will begin the download process when it's triggered. Associate the timer with the indexPath (or cell).

In `UITableViewControllerdelegate::tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:`: kill the timer if it hasn't already gone off.

Comment: The OP raises concerns about killing a connection that is almost done. What do you think about keeping a list of outstanding requests that start getting canceled when the cap has been reached?

Comment: Hm. So if the user quickly scrolled through table cells 1-10, and ends up looking at the 11th, wouldn't the 11th image just never show, since it's request hit the limit?

Comment: It would cancel the oldest request in the queue if the cap was reached. That way it could always start new requests when new cells become visible.

Comment: That works too. Useful if you don't want to tie the number of requests to the number of visible table cells.

Comment: You could tune the number to give you the best performance depending on the application. I'm pretty sure this is how apps like Facebook handle their table loading.

Comment: @CrimsonChris your solution is great but this isn't possible using `NSURLSession` because tehre are no `NSOperation`s. What else came to my mind... Fire timer and start downloading after a certain time so if the cell is visible for more than some time it'll fire downloading.

Answer (score -1):

There is a method of UITableViewCell that you can override: `prepareForReuse`. It will get called when table view is no longer need this cell and reusing memory for another cell that is becoming visible.

I think it will be a good start for you to cancel request associated with this cell.

Comment: There's no guarantee of when prepareForReuse will get called, other than before it gets re-displayed, afaik.

Comment: Much safer to go with didEndDisplayingCell.

Comment: All I'm saying - there is already infrastructure to reuse resources associated with table cell. Before anybody has to start implementing their own - I suggest to look into existing one.

Comment: I don't think so. I think relying to didEndDisplaying is more complicated and might not be necessary.

Comment: You can't know how many cells the table view will create before returning a cached one, and therefore you can't actually rely on prepareForReuse in a predictable manner. Using didEndDisplayingCell is correct.

Comment: @Colin is correct. This solution relies on an implementation detail that is opaque to those outside of Apple.